# Call method from another class DBContext

Tags: c#, methods, dbcontext

From several other classes I want to call this command to get the next id number. If there is 10 records, I want the number 11 returned.

> Table1.id = NextId("table1");

```
public class Test
{
    private PrenDBContext db = new PrenDBContext();

    public NextId(string table)
    {
        return MaxId = db.Raknare.Where(x => x.Column.Equals(table)).Max(x => x.ID) + 1;
    }
}
```

If I put public *static* NextId I cant use *db*..

Answer (score 1):

Create a new context every time `NextId` is called.  Don't try to re-use the contexts between calls.  Due to connection pooling (which you should ensure is enabled, if it's not) creating a new context is not particularly expensive.  In fact holding onto a context when it's not needed can be far more resource intensive.

Additionally, be careful about race conditions here.  If you're looking to figure out what the ID of a new item is, you should *really* avoid trying to solve this problem on your own.  Just use a column type that allows the DB to assign its own unique value for each row.  Currently you need to deal with the case where another record is created after you run this query but before you add the new record (if that is indeed what you're doing).  This is *very* hard to manage offsite form the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `PrenDBContext`  static as well:

```
public class Test 
{
        private static PrenDBContext db = new PrenDBContext();

        public static  NextId(string table)
        {
            return MaxId = db.Raknare.Where(x => x.Column.Equals(table)).Max(x => x.ID) + 1;
        } 
}
```

It is though more recommended to create a separate `PrenDBContext`  each time you call a `NextId` method:

```
public class Test 
{
        public static  NextId(string table)
        {
            var db = new PrenDBContext();
            return MaxId = db.Raknare.Where(x => x.Column.Equals(table)).Max(x => x.ID) + 1;   
        } 
}
```

Comment: You're never disposing of either connection.